# JavaHL 1.8 and JavaHL 1.9 in one PC

Tags: eclipse, subversive, javahl

In first my Ubuntu machine `JavaHL 1.8` is used in `Mars Eclipse`. Second machine contains `JavaHL 1.9` is used in `Oxygen 2 Eclipse`. I got some problems while working with SVN in `Oxygen 2` and decided to install and use `JavaHL 1.8`. Can I have both `JavaHL 1.9` and `JavaHL 1.8` in one machine? How to install `JavaHL 1.8` in order to get selection of two SVN connectors in `Oxygen 2`?